# Add multiple arguments to a server action using useFormState hook in NextJs 14

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, prisma

I have a server action that has 3 parameters (**previous state** - for managing the user feedback with **useFormState**, the actual **formData** and an **array of objects** that i receive from user). How do i use the useFormState hook to pass these arguments to the server action?

Here is my server action:

```
"use server";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
const prisma = new PrismaClient();
type TagType = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
};
export const addBlogPost = async (
  prevState: any,
  formData: FormData,
  tagsArr: TagType[]
) => {
  try {
    const title = formData.get("title");
    const content = formData.get("content");
    const userId = formData.get("userId");
    if (title === "" || content === "") {
      return {
        status: 400,
        message: "You must add a title and some content for your blog post",
      };
    } else {
      const blogPost = await prisma.blogPost.create({
        data: {
          title: title as string,
          content: content as string,
          user: { connect: { id: userId as string } },
          tags: {
            connect: tagsArr.map((tag) => ({ id: tag.id, name: tag.name })),
          },
        },
      });
      console.log(blogPost);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return {
      status: 500,
      message: "Oops... Something gone wrong",
    };
  }
};
```